# how can I debug the code of my arduino without arduino zero

Tags: debugging, arduino, serial-port, thread-safety, arduino-ide

The only way I know how to debug an arduino is usen the SerialPort which is like using a odd tool after trying vsCode in my job. Could someone show me how is it the prefered way to acomplish it?

SerialPort is just too slow and if I want to know what is happening in a critical section is not the best way to do it.

Comment: debugging critical sections is always problematic :)

Comment: why did you accept the answer? it doesn't help you and is not right

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v2/tutorials/ide-v2-debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino doesn’t come with a custom debugging tool. I`m sorry to tell you that unlike most other IDEs, there is no official Arduino debugging feature inside the arduino IDE.

However, thanks to the community we have access to unofficial tools like using Arduino simulators and emulators or and external software debuggin tool.
Personally I prefer simulator. Once you get use of it is simpler.

More about this here: https://www.circuito.io/blog/arduino-debugging/

Comment: Arduino IDE 2 supports debugging of SAMD boards. Arduino Zero has the debugger on board but other SAMD boards (MKR) can be debugged with external debugger

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v2/tutorials/ide-v2-debugger